# Serverless Webpack generates empty files in ZIP package

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

I'm facing with a rather annoying and frustrating anomaly with Serverless + Webpack generating empty files in the `.serverless/<package>.zip`.

[image]

#### Config

`serverless.yml`

```yaml
...
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
...
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack")
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")
// const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  optimization: {
    // We do not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  // node: false,
  // devtool: 'inline-cheap-module-source-map',
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    targets: { node: '12' },
                    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                    corejs: 3,
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // TODO
    // new CopyPlugin([
      // 'path/to/specific/file',
      // 'recursive/directory/**',
    // ]),
  ],
};
```

#### Additional Data

- ***Serverless-Webpack Version***: "serverless-webpack": "^5.3.5",
- ***Webpack version***: "webpack": "4.44.2",
- ***Serverless Framework Version***: 1.83.2
- ***Operating System***: MacOS

I have tried other version combinations too: Serverless 2.20, webpack 5.17.0, copy-webpack-plugin 7.0.0

Why empty files in ZIP??

**Update:**

I have just tried to run `sls package` in one of the [example projects](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/tree/master/examples/babel-webpack-4) with same result, empty files in ZIP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: downgrade Node JS from version 15 to 13. (Did not try 14.)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks.

I downgraded nodejs from 15.7.0 to 15.4.0 and it's working fine now.

Comment: I've wasted so much time on playing chess with versions I went for the first working solution. 

Answer (score 0):

Use nvm to manage different versions of the node.

The issue was happening for me with node version v15.8.0. Resolved by downgrading system version to v14.15.5 using nvm.

Reference - https://forum.serverless.com/t/empty-files-in-uploaded-zip/13777